# emotion react class concatenation

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, emotion

How to resolve problem with class concatenation?

#### Expected Result

All `div`s have outline. First div has **red** outline. Second, and third have **blue** outline.

#### Current Result

All `div`s have outline. First, and second div have **red** outline. Third has **blue** outline.

#### Environment

```json
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.8",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
```

#### Code

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css } from "@emotion/react";

const outlineCss = css`
  outline: 1px solid red;

  & + & {
    outline: 2px solid blue;
  }
`;

const marginYCss = css`
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

export default Component() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div css={[outlineCss, marginYCss]}>first</div>
      <div css={outlineCss}>second</div>
      <div css={outlineCss}>third</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```